# Coequalizers in the category of partially ordered sets

Tags: category-theory, order-theory, equivalence-relations, limits-colimits

Let $X$ and $Y$ be posets and $f, g : X \to Y$ be monotonic functions. I wish to construct the coequalizer $(Z, \; h : Y \to Z)$ of $f$ and $g$.

**My attempt**

I first define the relation $R \subseteq Y*Y$ by $y R y' \Leftrightarrow \exists x \in X, \; y = f(x) \;\;\&\;\; y' = g(x)$. Let $\equiv$ be the equivalence relation defined as the reflexive, transitive and symmetric closure of $R$.

For $Z$ I take the equivalence classes of $\equiv$ equipped with the order $[y]_{\equiv} \le [y']_{\equiv}$ iff $y \le y'$.

For $h$ I take the function that maps $y$ to $[y]_{\equiv}$ and I need to show that this function is monotonic.

**Questions**

Is my construction right? If yes, how to prove the monotonicity of $h$? If no, how to correct it?

More generally, can this construction be extended to DCPOs (Directed Complete Partial Orders)? To algebraic DCPOs? In those cases $f$ and $g$ are Scott-continuous and $h$ must be proved Scott-continuous.

Comment: The ordering isn’t well defined, you’re going to need to take a more aggressive quotient.

Comment: @FShrike What is wrong? What is the correct definition?

Comment: Off the top of my head I’m not sure but think about examples like this: $\Bbb N/E$ where $E$ is the relation that identifies evens with evens and odds with odds. The correct quotient in the poset category isn’t just $\{0,1\}$, it’s actually a singleton. Because $2\le3\le4$ means $\text{even}\le\text{odd}\le\text{even}$ so that the even and odd classes must actually be identified: at the end of the day there is only one equivalence class

Comment: The above can be construed as a coequaliser by taking the coequaliser of the projections $\pi_{1,2}:E\to\Bbb N$

Comment: Off the top of my head, what I'd try to do to construct a coequalizer would be something like: first, take the intersection of all preorders on $Y$ which contain $\le_Y$, as well as the images of $(f, g) : X \to Y \times Y$ and $(g, f) : X \to Y \times Y$.  Then, take the canonical partial order quotient of that preorder on $Y$.

Comment: The condition defining $R$ makes no mention of $y$ and $y'$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thank you! This was a typo that is now corrected.